# How to wait until the path is drawn on canvas in android?

Tags: android, svg, path, android-canvas, androidsvg

I have different Path's in my List and I want to draw one Path on Canvas at a time but I am executing a for loop and while drawing one path another path starts to be drawn on Canvas.
What can I do to stop the for loop or wait until the path is drawn.
for loop is given below.

```
                   for ( i = 0; i < mPaths.size(); i++) {
                        SvgHelper.SvgPath svgPath = mPaths.get(i);
                        svgPath.paint.setAlpha(255);
                        canvas.drawPath(svgPath.path, svgPath.paint);                           
                    }
```

onDraw(Canvas canvas) method code.
Size of mPaths List variable is 24.
The thing is want to draw one path at a time but when i keep it in for loop all 24 paths are drawn simultaneously.

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // Log.w("On draw", "Executing Ondraw");

        synchronized (mSvgLock) {

            canvas.save();

            canvas.translate(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop()
                    - getPaddingBottom());

                canvas.save();

                canvas.translate(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop()
                        - getPaddingBottom());

                for (i = 0; i < mPaths.size(); i++) {
                    //
                    Log.w("no of times", String.valueOf(i));
                    //
                    synchronized (Lock) {

                        SvgHelper.SvgPath svgPath = mPaths.get(i);
                        svgPath.paint.setAlpha(255);
                        canvas.drawPath(svgPath.path, svgPath.paint);
                    }

//                  break;
                }

                canvas.restore();

        }

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(0.0f, getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - mRadius
                * 3.0f);
    }
```

Comment: If I understand it right - you need to animate drawing, so in draw loop you should not use list.size() but variable from 1 to list.size() and variable increases at the end of onDraw and calls invalidate or postdelayed method with invalidate task

Comment: Sorry @curioushikhov but can you please explain what you saying. because I am not getting that..

Comment: multiple threads draw the paths?

Comment: No onDraw() method runs 24 times draw's the path object and until the path.close is not encountered for every Path object it is drawn.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NxG3BE9QCg @MarcoAcierno as in this video all Paths are drawn simultaneously I want to draw Paths one by one.. the video is shown that how my Paths are drawn.

Comment: Thank you friends for all your comments and answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Object` for lock and put you core code in Synchronized block.

Try this;

```
Object lock = new Object();
for ( i = 0; i < mPaths.size(); i++) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        SvgHelper.SvgPath svgPath = mPaths.get(i);
        svgPath.paint.setAlpha(255);
        canvas.drawPath(svgPath.path, svgPath.paint);
    }               
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
I have tried this but it is not working. 
Its drawing the same.
Posted my onDraw(Canvas canvas) method code.